# How to debug Asp.net mvc hanging/not responding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, freeze

I have a asp.net mvc site that sometimes hangs. Any idea how to debug this? It doesn't happen locally on the local debug server, only when i upload to a remote test server.

To explain better: I have a page that triggers 6 ajax requests as soon as it is loaded. I see that 2 of them always hangs. Then if i change the parameters everything loads ok.

Another page triggers the requests only after it's loaded, and most time works, but sometimes it hangs as well. In this page i see that it oftenly hangs on the most consuming requests, the "easier" ones respond well.

Comment: Are you able to post any example code? The JS code and controller actions would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up some logging in the server-side page that provides the request-- at least then you can start to gather some data on the routines in question.